# Is it possible to get dynamic ParameterContext value with Expression Language in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I get ParameterContext value with dynamic name in Apache NiFi?
For example, for each flowfile I need to get parameter according to ${type} attribute of this flowfile.

Like: #{${type}_parameter}.

Is it possible to do this in NiFi 1.19.1?

I tried ${literal('{${type}_parameter}'):prepend('#'):evaluateELString()}, but it always returns empty string.

Comment: I think it's not possible